# ios : unable to make core plot graph smaller

Tags: iphone, ios, core-plot

Am trying to plot a line chart in an iPhone app using Core Plot. Am unable to draw the graph to the small size in iPhone screen. This is what I have set in the storyboard (actually i want smaller than this, since I want to fit two graphs in a screen, but this was the minimum size that it started showing the plots, though it is showing only 2 plot out of 5)

[image]

And this is what is getting displayed in the phone

[image]

I removed the padding for the graph & tried, in vain.

In the above scenario, i have set padding to:

```
        self.graph.plotAreaFrame.paddingBottom = 2.0;
        self.graph.plotAreaFrame.paddingTop = 2.0;
        self.graph.plotAreaFrame.paddingLeft = 2.0;
        self.graph.plotAreaFrame.paddingRight = 2.0;
```

and I have set the graph hosting view's bounds to the bounds of the view in the storyboard.

Kindly help. I think it should be possible to draw a small graph, but not sure why it is not allowing it.
What am I setting wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I increased the yRange (plotSpace.yRange) and it worked! Now it shows all the 5 data plots.